# Having problems getting electron builder to sign a mac build

Tags: macos, certificate, electron, electron-builder, dmg

I don't know why `electron-builder` cannot find a valid identity.

Using the environment variable to debug, I always end up with the same problem where it says there is no valid identity despite listing there to be 1 valid identity underneath.

- I have tried specifying the cert name as the "identity" property of the top level key "mac" in package json and leaving it out.
- I have tried specifying the keychain (CSC_KEYCHAIN) to login.
- I have tried adding the "Developer ID Application: ****" cert to login, System, and custom keychains (I don't know why electron builder keeps making extra keychains called "1").
- I have tried adding an "Apple Root CA" to all those keychains from the previous line.
- I have tried specifying and omitting CSC_NAME, CSC_LINK + CSC_KEY_PASSWORD.
- I have tried CSC_IDENTITY_AUTO_DISCOVERY as false.

Running the command line from this [page](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/ev-code-signing-for-mac-osx.htm) appears to work (as running `spctl -a -t exec -vv 'Appname.dmg'` gives back "source=Unnotarized Developer ID" ), but I would like to follow the automatic notarization process suggested [here](https://kilianvalkhof.com/2019/electron/notarizing-your-electron-application/) which is based off of [electron-builder #3870](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3870)

When I specify the identity in `package json`, the closest I get to is saying

```
Identity name is specified, but no valid identity with this name in the keychain identity=***** allIdentities=

1) BBBBBBBBB "Developer ID Application: ***** (XXXXX)"
1 identities found

Valid identities only

1) BBBBBBBBBB "Developer ID Application: ***** (XXXXX)" <---lists the exact one above

1 valid identities found
at/........
```

When I run security `find-identity -v`, or `security find-identity -v -p codesigning`, the exact same cert appears again.

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Have you found the right identity?

Comment: I've the same issue. Do you remember how you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it cost me considerable amount of time until I eventually figured out the solution. This should probably work for everyone who face this issue.

When I renewed my Apple Developer membership, I found I already had two certificates under my account, so I downloaded those and added them to my Keychain. However, Electron-builder refused to pick them up during app packaging. It always picked other irrelevant certificates instead.

What I then did was to [create new certificates](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/create-certificates/create-developer-id-certificates/) and downloaded those. Once I added them to Keychain, and re-ran Electron-builder, it immediately picked them up and signed my app correctly.

What was the difference between these new certificates and the old ones? Well, one prominent thing is that these new certificates contained their `private key` (just as [mentioned](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/4935#issuecomment-846311686) by a user on GitHub).

So it must mean the first two certificates I had downloaded were created with my old computer (some years back) and so their private keys were not present when I downloaded them from devevloper.apple.com. When creating the new certs, the Form prompts you to link a `certificate singing request file` (don't worry it's all in the instructions from the first link I shared), which I believe contains the missing private key that my older certificates didn't have.

### --

***Side Note (This next bit is slightly unrelated):***

When Electron-builder successfully picks your certs and attempts to sign your App, you maybe prompted to enter the key password to allow the signing. In my case, I had no idea what the password would be (computer password didn't work), so I instead:

1. went to Keychain
2. expand the certificate to view the private key
3. right click on the private key
4. click "Get Info"
5. a small pop-up will appear with an "Access Control" tab, click the "Access Control" tab and select "Allow all apps access this item"
6. click save
7. it will prompt you for a password but your computer password will work in this case.
8. Once that's done, you can run Electron-builder again.
9. Of course you can go back to undo this setting once your application is done packaging.