# electron-builder: Identity name is specified, but no valid identity with this name in the keychain

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am trying to build and sign my Electron application. However, I keep receiving an error message about code signing certificates. (Sensitive values have been sanitized.)

*electron-builder.js*

```
module.exports = {
    mac: {
        identity: 'Apple Development: me@company.com (37HSQ92C44)'
    }
}
```

Output from `electron-builder`

```
• skipped macOS application code signing reason=Identity name is specified, but no valid identity with this name in the keychain identity=Apple Development: me@company.com (37HSQ92C44) allIdentities=
    1) [Redacted]
    2) [Redacted]
    3) [Redacted]
    4) 4099C29CB27A058D14DFAD52A5BB5A4FEE1B293E "Apple Development: me@company.com (37HSQ92C44)"
    5) [Redacted]
       5 identities found

    Valid identities only
    1) [Redacted]
    2) 4099C29CB27A058D14DFAD52A5BB5A4FEE1B293E "Apple Development: me@company.com (37HSQ92C44)"
       2 valid identities found
```

`electron-builder` reports that it can see the identity that I wish to use. However, it's not able to match the identity name that I specify in the configuration file with that identity. I have tried all conceivable variations that I can think of to use in `identity` property, but none do the job:

- 4099C29CB27A058D14DFAD52A5BB5A4FEE1B293E
- 4099C29CB27A058D14DFAD52A5BB5A4FEE1B293E "Apple Development: me@company.com (37HSQ92C44)"
- Apple Development: me@company.com (37HSQ92C44)
- "Apple Development: me@company.com (37HSQ92C44)"
- 37HSQ92C44

I have also tried several combinations of `CSC_NAME`, `CSC_LINK`, `CSC_KEYCHAIN`, etc. to no avail.

Comment: Please see the answer in this other post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77345361/4088675

Answer (score 5):

You can try to remove `Apple Development:` from `identity`.

```
module.exports = {
    mac: {
        identity: 'me@company.com (37HSQ92C44)'
    }
}
```

Comment: We can also provide only email: `mac: { identity: 'me@company.com' }`